# Map one Dataframe to a second Dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub, stringr

I have two dataframes and want to map both and give a binary value 1 if present else 0.

**1st DF**

```
id       1_1   1_2   1_3   1_4   1_5   1_6   1_7   1_8   1_9   1_10  1_freq
111.txt  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
112.txt  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
113.txt  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
114.txt  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
115.txt  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
116.txt  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

**2nd DF**

```
id                 cats
111.cats           1,7,1
112.cats           1,1,2|1,3,2
113.cats           1,10,1|1,6,2
114.cats           1,4,2
115.cats           1,5,1
116.cats           1,1,2|1,8,1
```

In 2nd `DF$cats` first row have `1,7,1` where `1` and `7` combines and makes `1_7` column and on this column binary value 1 is placed and on remaining column `0` is placed and last `1` number goes to the `1_freq` column,
and if any row has more than 1 category like this `1,10,1|1,6,2` where `1,10,1` goes to `1_10` column and `1,6,2` goes to `1_6` column and the frequency of both category sums up and goes to `1_freq` column.

**DF Should look like this**

```
id       1_1   1_2   1_3   1_4   1_5   1_6   1_7   1_8   1_9   1_10  1_freq
111.txt  0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
112.txt  1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     4
113.txt  0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     3
114.txt  0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     2
115.txt  0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
116.txt  1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     3
```

Hope question is clear.
Thankyou

Comment: yes thanks for pointing out ..edited it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`.  We expand the rows of the dataset by splitting at `|` of the 'cats' column, then `separate` the 'cats' into two column by splitting at the last `,` , grouped by 'id', get the `sum` of the 'freq' column, extract the numbers at the end of the 'cats', convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified, create a column of 1s ('val'), `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
o1 <- df2 %>% 
       separate_rows(cats, sep = "[|]") %>% 
       separate(cats, into = c('cats', 'freq'), 
           sep=",(?=[^,]+$)", convert = TRUE) %>%
       group_by(id) %>%
       mutate(freq = sum(freq), 
              cats = factor(str_extract(cats, "\\d+$"), levels = 1:10), 
              val = 1)  %>% 
       spread(cats, val, fill = 0) %>% 
       rename_at(-1, ~ paste0('1_', .))
```

Now, we assign values for the columns that are common with the initial dataset ('df1')

```
df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
df1[names(o1)[-1]] <- o1[-1]
df1
#       id 1_1 1_2 1_3 1_4 1_5 1_6 1_7 1_8 1_9 1_10 1_freq
#1 111.txt   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0    0      1
#2 112.txt   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      4
#3 113.txt   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0    1      3
#4 114.txt   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    0      2
#5 115.txt   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0    0      1
#6 116.txt   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    0      3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("111.txt", "112.txt", "113.txt", "114.txt", 
"115.txt", "116.txt"), `1_1` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_2` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_3` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_4` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_5` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_6` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_7` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_8` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_9` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_10` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1_freq` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = c("111.cats", "112.cats", "113.cats", "114.cats", 
"115.cats", "116.cats"), cats = c("1,7,1", "1,1,2|1,3,2", "1,10,1|1,6,2", 
"1,4,2", "1,5,1", "1,1,2|1,8,1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thankyou it worked...i have been struggling a lot..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although  the question is tagged [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr), I was curious how a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) answer would look like.

As `df1` is filled with `NA` except for the `id` column and the `id` columns only differ in the trailing part (`txt` vs `cats`) the answer below suggests to create `df1` completely from the data contained in `df2`:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
long <- setDT(df2)[, strsplit(cats, "[|]"), by = id][
  , c(.(id = id), tstrsplit(V1, ","))][
    , V3 := factor(V3, levels = 1:10)]
df1 <- dcast(long, id ~ V3, function(x) pmax(1, length(x)), 
             value.var = "V3", drop = FALSE, fill = 0)[
               long[, sum(as.integer(V4)), by = id], on = "id", freq := V1][
                 , id := stringr::str_replace(id, "cats$", "txt")][
                   , setnames(.SD, names(.SD)[-1], paste0("1_", names(.SD)[-1]))]
df1
```

> ```
>         id 1_1 1_2 1_3 1_4 1_5 1_6 1_7 1_8 1_9 1_10 1_freq
> 1: 111.txt   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0    0      1
> 2: 112.txt   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      4
> 3: 113.txt   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0    1      3
> 4: 114.txt   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    0      2
> 5: 115.txt   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0    0      1
> 6: 116.txt   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    0      3
> ```

#### Explanation

After coersion to data.table, `df2` is reshaped from a "stringified" wide format into `long` form by splitting the `cats` column at "|" first and then by splitting the comma-separated parts into separate columns `V2` to `V4`.

Then `V3` is turned from character to factor to preserve the order of columns when `dcast()` is called to reshape from long to wide format again. As the OP has requested to show a `1` if at least one combination exists, the custom function definition `function(x) pmax(1, length(x))` has to be used here instead of simply `length`. In an *update join*, the sum of frequencies is appended as column `freq`. Finally, "cats" is replaced by "txt" in the `id` column and the column names (except the `id` column) are prefixed by "1_".

#### Data

```
df2 <- data.table::fread("id                 cats
111.cats           1,7,1
112.cats           1,1,2|1,3,2
113.cats           1,10,1|1,6,2
114.cats           1,4,2
115.cats           1,5,1
116.cats           1,1,2|1,8,1", data.table = FALSE)
```